# use unix commands to filter and sort data

Tags: unix, awk

Let's say I have data as below:

```
aaa m7
aaa m9
aaa m7
aaa m7
aaa m7
ccc m9
ccc m7
ccc m7
bbb m7
bbb m9
bbb m7
ddd m7
```

How could I sort it into:

```
aaa m9
bbb m9
ccc m9
ddd m7
```

using unix commands (sort, uniq, etc.)?

What I need is sort all data and then filter out all data with same field#1.

Comment: That looks filtered, not sorted.

Comment: edit my question, hope it is clear now

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Your edit hasn't really changed anything.

Comment: it is combination of sort and filter

Comment: So you want an algorithm that returns the 2nd, 6th and 10th row of a file? Exampes are good, but please explain what the algorithm should do in your own words.

Comment: Wow, good question. It's easy to get the right output if you know the input and can grep for something specific, but it's quite a hard question to solve in the general sense. This is for extra credit or something?

Comment: I would rewrite the spec to say "I need to filter the data so each field 1 is unique and field 2 is the highest value for each field 1. The results should be sorted on field 1."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes your input and gives your output. I'm not sure whether it's what you want, given the vagueness of your specification...

```
$ cat ./4162059.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    if (d[$1] < $2) {
        d[$1] = $2
    }
}

END {
    for (k in d) {
       print k " " d[k]
    }
}

$ cat ./4162059.txt 
aaa m7
aaa m9
aaa m7
aaa m7
aaa m7
ccc m9
ccc m7
ccc m7
bbb m7
bbb m9
bbb m7
ddd m7

$ ./4162059.awk 4162059.txt | sort
aaa m9
bbb m9
ccc m9
ddd m7
```

The `awk` program keeps note of the value of the column 1 with the 'highest' value of column 2 and prints them once it has parsed the whole input file. The output is then sorted by `sort` on the command-line.

Comment: Awk is under-used and great for this kind of thing. +1.

Comment: Thanks @Conrad. It's underused by me, too. I tend to use it only as a `cut` + `grep` hybrid :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the data resides in data.txt, use:

```
sort < data.txt > sorted.txt
```

If you just want the m9's, use:

```
grep m9 < data.txt | sort | uniq > sorted_m9.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do.

I'm assuming you want to print only unique values in column 1 with the largest corresponding value in column 2 because your output has `m9`.

```
sort -V input | 
perl -nae '$H{$F[0]}=$F[1];END{for(sort keys %H){print $_." ".$H{$_}."\n";}}'
```

Sample run:

```
$ cat file
aaa m9
aaa m10
ccc m9
ccc m7
bbb m7
bbb m9
bbb m7
ddd m11
ddd m1
$ sort -V file | perl -nae '$H{$F[0]} = $F[1];END{for(sort keys %H){print $_." ".$H{$_}."\n";}}'
aaa m10
bbb m9
ccc m9
ddd m11
$
```